# xslt is not calling JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt

I'm using xslt to transform xml to html.
Here is .xml file.

```
 <ImportOrganizationUtility-logging>
  <log-session module-name="ImportOrganizationUtility" end="17:54:06" start="17:52:19">
    <ou ou-name="Exchange" status="Success">
      <Steps>
        <step1 name="Add User" Username="hcimportuser3" PlanId="2" end="17:52:29" start="17:52:26" status="Success" > <log-description><![CDATA[  
          User added successfully.
]]></log-description> </step1>
        <step2 name="ImportOrganization" end="17:53:35" start="17:52:29" status="Success" >  <log-description><![CDATA[  
          Imported successfully.
]]></log-description></step2>
        <step3 name="Segregation Utility Operations" MailDomain="exchange.com" end="17:53:58" start="17:53:36" status="Success">
          <log-description><![CDATA[  
          Operation performed successfully.
]]></log-description>
        </step3>
      </Steps>
      <log-description><![CDATA[Organization 'Exchange' imported successfully]]></log-description>
    </ou>
    <ou ou-name="APICall2" status="Failed">
      <Steps>
        <step1 name="Add User and Sell Plan" Username="hcimportuser3" PlanId="2" end="17:54:02" start="17:54:01" status="Success" />
        <step2 name="ImportOrganization" end="17:54:06" start="17:54:02" status="Failed">
          <log-description><![CDATA[Detailed error message.]]></log-description>
        </step2>
      </Steps>
      <log-description><![CDATA[Detailed error message.]]></log-description>
    </ou>
  </log-session>
</ImportOrganizationUtility-logging>
```

I'm creating two tables one is sub table inside tr>td and its `style="display:none"` applied on it. Bot tables are creating fine.

The problem I'm facing is that I have created a JavaScript function and calling it on parent table row click to toggle sub table but its not working. I added alert but not receiving any alert on row click which show that `toggleRow()` is not calling.

Anyone who can let me know what is wrong here. I tried but couldn't get it.
Here is .xsl file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <style>

        </style>
          <header>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css"/>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css"/>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                 function toggleRow(itemID){ 
                    alert(itemID);
                      if ((document.getElementById("tr" + itemID).style.display == 'none')) 
                      { 
                        document.getElementById("tr" + itemID).style.display = 'inline'; 
                      } else { 
                        document.getElementById("tr" + itemID).style.display = 'none'; 
                      }             
            </script>
             
          </header>
      <body>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table id="table" class="table table-striped moveabletable">
            <thead>
              <tr class="table100-head" >
                <th class="medium col-sm-2" colspan="1" >Organization Name</th>
                <!-- <th class="medium col-sm-2" ></th> -->
                <th class="small  col-sm-1">Owner Name</th>
                <th class="small  col-sm-1">Status</th>
                <th>Description</th>
              </tr>
              </thead>
              
              <tbody>
              <xsl:for-each select="ImportOrganizationUtility-logging/log-session/ou">            
                <xsl:sort select="@status" order="descending"/>
                <xsl:variable name="i" select="position()"/>
                <tr >
                    <xsl:attribute name="onclick">javascript:toggleRow(<xsl:value-of select="$i"/>)</xsl:attribute>
                  <td><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"> </i> <xsl:value-of select="@ou-name"/>
                    <!-- <a  onClick="toggleRow('{$i}')"> <xsl:value-of select="@ou-name"/></a> -->
                  </td>
                  <td><xsl:value-of select="Steps/step1/@Username"/></td>
                  
                  <xsl:choose>
                     <xsl:when test="@status='Failed'">
                      <td style="color:red"><xsl:value-of select="@status"/></td>
                      </xsl:when>
                       <xsl:otherwise > 
                          <td style="color:green"><xsl:value-of select="@status"/></td>
                      </xsl:otherwise>
                   </xsl:choose>                     
                  <td style="text-align:left"><xsl:value-of select="log-description"/></td>               
                  
                </tr>
                <tr id="tr{$i}" style="display:none">
                <td colspan="4">
                  <table id="table" class="table table-striped moveabletable ">
                        <thead>
                          <tr class="table100-head" >
                            <th class="medium col-sm-2" colspan="1" >Step</th>
                            <th class="small  col-sm-1">Status</th>
                            <th>Description</th>
                          </tr>
                        </thead>
                      
                        <tbody>
                            <tr >
                              <td>1</td>
                              <!-- <td><xsl:value-of select="Steps/step1/@status"/></td> -->
                              
                              <xsl:choose>
                                 <xsl:when test="@status='Failed'">
                                  <td style="color:red"><xsl:value-of select="Steps/step1/@status"/></td>
                                  </xsl:when>
                                   <xsl:otherwise > 
                                      <td style="color:green"><xsl:value-of select="Steps/step1/@status"/></td>
                                  </xsl:otherwise>
                               </xsl:choose>                             
                             
                              <td style="text-align:left"><xsl:value-of select="Steps/step1/log-description"/></td> 
                              
                            </tr>
                             <xsl:if test="Steps/step2/@status!=''">
                                <tr >                           
                                  <td>2</td>
                                  <!-- <td><xsl:value-of select="Steps/step1/@status"/></td> -->
                                  
                                  <xsl:choose>
                                     <xsl:when test="@status='Failed'">
                                      <td style="color:red"><xsl:value-of select="Steps/step2/@status"/></td>
                                      </xsl:when>
                                       <xsl:otherwise > 
                                          <td style="color:green"><xsl:value-of select="Steps/step2/@status"/></td>
                                      </xsl:otherwise>
                                   </xsl:choose>                             
                                 
                                  <td style="text-align:left"><xsl:value-of select="Steps/step2/log-description"/></td> 
                                </tr>
                              </xsl:if>
                             <xsl:if test="Steps/step3/@status!=''">
                                <tr >
                                  <td>3</td>
                                  
                                  <xsl:choose>
                                     <xsl:when test="@status='Failed'">
                                      <td style="color:red"><xsl:value-of select="Steps/step3/@status"/></td>
                                      </xsl:when>
                                       <xsl:otherwise > 
                                          <td style="color:green"><xsl:value-of select="Steps/step3/@status"/></td>
                                      </xsl:otherwise>
                                   </xsl:choose>                             
                                 
                                  <td style="text-align:left"><xsl:value-of select="Steps/step3/log-description"/></td> 
                                </tr>
                              </xsl:if>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                  
                  </td> 
                
                </tr>
                    
              </xsl:for-each>               
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
      </div>
        
      </body>
    </html>     
  </xsl:template>    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is the image of parent table [image]

And want to show sub table on row click as in this image [image]

Any help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: So what does the console  (F12) of the browser show, any error messages or warnings? The whole code looks odd, a table row, as its default CSS `display` value certainly doesn't use `inline`. In general, I would simplify the XSLT to generate the attribute event handler to e.g. `<tr onclick="toggleRow({$i});">` and the function to e.g. `function toggleRow(id) { document.getElementById('tr' + i).style.display = document.getElementById('tr' + i).style.display === 'none' ? '' : 'none'; }`.

Comment: Your function is not registered with on click as it did not exist when events are registered

Comment: Also HTML should have `<head>` and not `<header>`. And you should move the `style` inside of the `head` element.

Comment: @MartinHonnen it's still not working as you mentioned in your first comment. Regarding to your second comment I tried with both `<head>` and `<header>` before even before posting question but couldn't get the result. In console (F12) there is no error message. Error count is also 0.

Comment: @KevinBrown thanks for your reply. Can you explain a little more how can I register it?

Comment: An explanation would be better if you explain more. Like do you insist on pure JS or using a library like jquery which greatly simplifies the task

Comment: @KevinBrown I don't insist on pure JS. I can also go for jQuery.

Comment: @KevinBrown I don't insist on pure JS. I can also go for jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JavaScript code

```
function toggleRow(itemID){ 
                alert(itemID);
                  if ((document.getElementById("tr" + itemID).style.display == 'none')) 
                  { 
                    document.getElementById("tr" + itemID).style.display = 'inline'; 
                  } else { 
                    document.getElementById("tr" + itemID).style.display = 'none'; 
                  }
```

lacks the closing curly brace `}` to close the function body, i.e. you want at least

```
function toggleRow(itemID){ 
                alert(itemID);
                  if ((document.getElementById("tr" + itemID).style.display == 'none')) 
                  { 
                    document.getElementById("tr" + itemID).style.display = 'inline'; 
                  } else { 
                    document.getElementById("tr" + itemID).style.display = 'none'; 
                  }  
}
```

As I said in a comment, I would suggest to shorten that to

```
function toggleRow(id) { 
  document.getElementById('tr' + id).style.display = document.getElementById('tr' + id).style.display === 'none' ? '' : 'none'; 
}
```

as it is usually better to just remove the inline style with `style.display = 'none'` to have the default setting kick in instead of trying to set an `inline` display on a table row.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm really amazed how I miss closing curly bracket. But still its not working even with your shorten suggestion it is not changing anything. I also add alert but no alert when I click on row.